# Assistance with First Yaml pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm writing my first Terraform YAML pipeline in Azure DevOps.  I define four repositories as resources, check them out and run to Terraform Plan.   The pipeline succeeds but only the first repository of Terraform runs. This is  based what is coming to the screen from that repositories' output.tf.  The others don't generate any output even when I define a output variable with a string value.  Something like this:

`output "rg_module_debug" { value="rg module ran" }`

Here is the pipeline code, any feedback on why the other code isn't running would be appreciated

```
    name: 'Naming Test'

    trigger:
    - None

    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest

    resources:
      repositories:
      - repository: VariablesRepo # identifier (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
        type: git #git refers to Azure Repos Git repos
        name: AzureTutorial/terraform-azurerm-variables-environment
        ref: main
      - repository: NameRepo # identifier (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
        type: git #git refers to Azure Repos Git repos
        name: AzureTutorial/terraform-azurerm-module-name
        ref: main
      - repository: NamingRepo # identifier (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
        type: git #git refers to Azure Repos Git repos
        name: AzureTutorial/terraform-azurerm-module-naming
        ref: main
      - repository: ResourceGrpRepo # identifier (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
        type: git #git refers to Azure Repos Git repos
        name: AzureTutorial/terraform-azurerm-module-resource_group
        ref: main


    stages:
      - stage: Install
        jobs:
          - job:
            timeoutInMinutes: 60 # how long to run the job before automatically cancelling
            cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 2 # how much time to give 'run always even if cancelled tasks' 
                     before stopping them 
            steps:
            - checkout: self
            - checkout: VariablesRepo
            - checkout: NameRepo
            - checkout: NamingRepo
            - checkout: ResourceGrpRepo
            - task: TerraformInstaller@0
              displayName: 'install'
              inputs:
               terraformVersion: 'latest'
            - task: TerraformCLI@0
              displayName: 'terraform init'
              inputs:
               provider: 'azurerm'
               command: 'init'
               workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform-azurerm-module-name'
               #environmentServiceName: TutorialSvcCon
            - task: TerraformCLI@0
              displayName: 'terraform plan'
              inputs:
                provider: 'azurerm'
                command: 'plan'
                workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform-azurerm-module-name'
                #environmentServiceName: TutorialSvcCon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking out multiple repositories therefore according to the documentation:

**Multiple repositories:**

> If you have multiple checkout steps in your job, your source code is
> checked out into directories named after the repositories as a
> subfolder of `s` in (Agent.BuildDirectory). If (Agent.BuildDirectory) is
> C:\agent_work\1 and your repositories are named tools and code, your
> code is checked out to C:\agent_work\1\s\tools and
> C:\agent_work\1\s\code.

Thus to achieve what you want you'd have to create one `TerraformCLI@0` task for each checked out repository.

Therefore your stages code would be:
...

```
stages:
      - stage: Install
        jobs:
          - job:
            timeoutInMinutes: 60 # how long to run the job before automatically cancelling
            cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 2 # how much time to give 'run always even if cancelled tasks' 
                     before stopping them 
            steps:
            - checkout: self
            - checkout: VariablesRepo
            - checkout: NameRepo
            - checkout: NamingRepo
            - checkout: ResourceGrpRepo
            - task: TerraformInstaller@0
              displayName: 'install'
              inputs:
               terraformVersion: 'latest'
            - task: TerraformCLI@0
              displayName: 'terraform init'
              inputs:
               provider: 'azurerm'
               command: 'init'
               workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/NameRepo'
               #environmentServiceName: TutorialSvcCon
            - task: TerraformCLI@0
              displayName: 'terraform plan'
              inputs:
                provider: 'azurerm'
                command: 'plan'
                workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/NameRepo'
                #environmentServiceName: TutorialSvcCon
```

If for instance you want to do the same operation for each repository then you add more tasks pointing to the RepositoryName as you correctly set up at the beginning:

```
            - task: TerraformCLI@0
              displayName: 'terraform init'
              inputs:
               provider: 'azurerm'
               command: 'init'
               workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/VariablesRepo'
               #environmentServiceName: TutorialSvcCon
            - task: TerraformCLI@0
              displayName: 'terraform plan'
              inputs:
                provider: 'azurerm'
                command: 'plan'
                workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/VariablesRepo'
                #environmentServiceName: TutorialSvcCon
```

And so forth.